# Why base_url() is returning invalid url?

Tags: codeigniter

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
    class Home extends CI_Controller    
    {
        function index()
        {   
             echo base_url();  
            }
} ?>
```

**Config**
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';

**Output**

> http://::1/ci/

I have URL helper already loaded. It should be http://localhost/ci/

Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not leave your base url blank

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
```

Then try this htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also autoload url helper `application > config > autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

And on controllers you do not need to have `?>` at end

```
<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller {

   function index(){   
      echo base_url();  
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert url in your config like below :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
```

Add below code in your app>config>autoload.php

```
//$autoload['helper'] = array();
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

And Replace your **.htaccess** by below script for remove index.php from url.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploaded_files|img_cache|jscal|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

After that your url will be `http://localhost/ci/home`.

Comment: Remove `system` from first RewriteCond line.